# Adding class to link in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a anchor tag and would like to add a class to it in my document ready function.  How do I do that?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: if you want to have it from the start, why not add it on the html directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {  
   /* domReady */
   $('a').addClass('yourclass');
});
```

of course if your link has an id use a more specific selector  like

```
 $('#yourlink').addClass('yourclass');
```

Comment: But the only thing is that I have 3 links and only want to add the class to one of them

Comment: @sachin, based on what rule ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $('#id1_of_a, #id2_of_a, #id3_of_a').addClass('myClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {  
   $('a:first').addClass('yourclass'); // suppose add class to first <a>
});
```

or

```
$('a:eq(1)').addClass('yourclass'); // suppose add class to second <a> and so on
```

or

```
$('a#some').addClass('yourclass'); // suppose add class to <a> have id 'some'
```